# How to give <form:input path="{java.util.set}"> to set the modelAttribute value?

Tags: spring, jsp, model-view-controller

I have a model that has the following structure:

```
class Person {
    private int id;
    private Set<Person> friends = new Set<Person>();
}
```

when I use the modelAttribute for this class in a `<form:form>`, how can I set the values for the friends attribute?

Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

Initially in your Model.java file add setter and getter of your fields i.e id and friends.

**Model.java**

```
public class Person {
    private int id;
    Set<String> friends= new HashSet<String>();
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public Set<String> getFriends() {
        return friends;
    }
    public void setFriends(Set<String> friends) {
        this.friends = friends;
    }
}
```

Then in your PersonController class code should look something like this :

**PersonController**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/savePerson", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String savePerson(@ModelAttribute("person") Person person){
    
    Person tempPerson = new Person();
    Set<String> frnd = new HashSet<String>();
    tempPerson.setId(person.getId());
    /* This code line depends on how you are planning to get the friends list from form and then add it to 'frnd' set by frnd.add() method and pass the set to following setter*/
    tempPerson.setFriends(frnd);
    personService.savePerson(tempPerson);
    return "redirect:/persons";
}
```

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for responding to my post.
My question is how can I map this modelattribute in the JSP side?
When I get the modelattribute in <form:form> how to give the Set to a <input path>?